# Do you still get the vampiric effect on illusions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some weapons/skills have a vampiric effect. Does it still give you life when hitting an enemy that is an illusion (summoned by an enemy with the illusion powerup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

I've been playing a barbarian since launch and when I use the Revenge skill that returns 5% life per hit I also gain life from hitting illusion monsters. The other players I've asked also confirm their skills return life at the same rate or hitting normal monsters.